What's the correct pronunciation of 'lure' in American English?
I saw different version of 'lure'.
One is: /lʊr/
But I think it sounds like /lu:r/
I'm confused about that. Thanks for your answering.

Pronunciation varies by dialect.

In the Philadelphia area, for example, many speakers pronounce "lure" and "lore"  the same.

@TimR - how about Baltimore?

@MichaelHarvey https://youtu.be/Eb4RdVNK_0I

@TimR - Cousin Mike from Bollmer! Brilliant! How about Kathy Bates in American Horror Story: Freak Show? ('I got so much crap from these linguists at Columbia').

LOL. I'd never seen that episode of Conan. :-)

Dictionary.com and wiktionary both say it's /lʊəɹ/. But pronunciation varies by dialect.  Listen to both those examples, and then you are 90% there, it's enough.
